# CSS/JQuery | When filtering elements, one part of the last element won't disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my HTML page, I have a list of elements I'm filtering (see image):

[image: Filtering_img]

Problem is, when I search for some value (as shown in next image), the `div` with last `button` won't dissappear.

[image: img_2]

It is the `div` from the last element (last car in the list for this example). So the link with the last car dissappears, but the `div` with the button stays there. When I search for the last car, everything is OK. Here I attach my code via snippet (with only necessary CSS):

```js
//Filtering
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBuilding").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".buildings a,.rooms a").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.around_link_div {
    position: relative;
}

.button_today_div{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.button_today_div button{
    background-color: #2b542c;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
   <input class="form-control" id="searchBuilding" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
 </div>

  <div id="building" class="list-group text-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 buildings">
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Porsche</a>
   </div>
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Audi</a>
   </div>
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">BMW</a>
   </div>
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Traktor</a>
   </div>
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Mercedes</a>
   </div>
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Volvo</a>
   </div>
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Volkswagen</a>
   </div>
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Chevrolet</a>
   </div>
   <div class="around_link_div">
    <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
    <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Opel</a>
   </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Excuse my lack of knowledge (still studying and front-end is not my strongest point).

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filtering selector ($(".buildings a,.rooms a")) only selects the anchors (<a ...), not the div that contains your button. Use $(".buildings .around_link_div,.rooms a") instead, i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBuilding").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".buildings .around_link_div,.rooms a").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Also, in the code you posted, ".rooms a" is redundant.

Comment: Oh, such a silly mistake. And yes, I forgot to remove "rooms a", it is linked with another page. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hide the wrapping `<div class="around_link_div">` instead of the `<a>` by traversing up using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
//Filtering
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchBuilding").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".buildings a,.rooms a").filter(function() {
      $(this).closest('.around_link_div').toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.around_link_div {
  position: relative;
}

.button_today_div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button_today_div button {
  background-color: #2b542c;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
      <input class="form-control" id="searchBuilding" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="building" class="list-group text-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 buildings">
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Porsche</a>
    </div>
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Audi</a>
    </div>
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">BMW</a>
    </div>
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Traktor</a>
    </div>
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Mercedes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Volvo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Volkswagen</a>
    </div>
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Chevrolet</a>
    </div>
    <div class="around_link_div">
      <div class="button_today_div"><button onclick="location.href='today.html'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">INFO</button></div>
      <a href="rooms.html" class="list-group-item hoverable">Opel</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need an overflow hidden in the css on the list-group element

CSS

```
.list-group {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is to narrow selection. I think you have to use `each` in this case too loop through objects:

`$(".buildings a,.rooms a").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle((this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) 
});`